# How to get $date + 5 to exclude weekends?

Tags: php, date

I have some pages that require a date to be set in the future (either 2 or 5 days as set by a variable).
This date needs to be only counting Monday - Friday, excluding weekends.

What I have so far ($tts is the variable of 2 or 5 depending on page);

```
$Today = date('N:m:y');
$NewDate = date('l \t\h\e jS \o\f F',strtotime($Today) + (24*3600*$tts));
$businessDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
echo $NewDate;
```

This works without excluding weekend days.
I have tried to use the $businessDays but I'm unsure of how I can use this to count what days are between $Today and $NewDate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$plusFive = strtotime( '+5 weekday' );
$plusFive = date( 'Y-m-d', $plusFive );
```

strtotime also takes a second parameter which could be the base for the +5.

Comment: You could use too `new \DateTime("+5 weekdays")`. I think the Date\Time library is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.
It should pick a weekday $tts days ahead.

```
$Today = date('N:m:y');
$NewDate = date('l \t\h\e jS \o\f F',strtotime($Today . '+' . $tts .' weekdays'));
echo $NewDate;
```

https://3v4l.org/4SX0m

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime option:

```
<?php
$start = new DateTime();
date_add( $start, date_interval_create_from_date_string( '5 weekdays' ) );
echo $start->format( 'd-m-Y' );
```

Comment: Why 3 lines if you could do just `new \DateTime("+5 weekdays")`?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if its weekend and then add 2 days for Saturday and Sunday like this:

```
$busDays = 3;
$day = date("w");
if( $day > 2 && $day <= 5 ) { /* if between Wed and Fri */
  $day += 2; /* add 2 more days for weekend */
}
$day += $busDays;
```