# Automatically set date input date

Tags: php, html

So I have a date input that automatically sets the date 8 days later like this:

```
<input type="date" name="pdate" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", time() + 691200); ?>" required>
```

So now this will display `03/13/2021` as the date, but is it possible to skip Saturday and Sunday, so if the date in 8 days is Saturday or Sunday, it will automatically set date as the Money after insted?

Comment: I would advise you to create either a javascript or php function that will be called and checks if it's a saturday or sunday and sets the date to the next monday if thats true

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764671/how-to-get-date-5-to-exclude-weekends/). There are multiple methods, but the best one is (at this moment) hidden in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764671/how-to-get-date-5-to-exclude-weekends/#comment68754368_40765115).

Comment: so first, is the answer of 3/13/2021 correct, or is your intention to have the output be 3/17/2021 .. 8 weekdays in the future?  second, you are concerned about the day that 8 days in the future lands on so 3/13/2021 would need to be shifted to 3/15/2021

Comment: @RyanH I want the value in date input to display date 8 days in the future, BUT - if the 8. day in the future is a Saturday or Sunday, I want it to automatically select the Monday after instead. If the 8 day in the future is a weekday, for example Wednesday, it should stay like that.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the functionalities you need? Like [checking if a date is weekend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php)? And with [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), next monday is trivial to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DateTime in PHP

Like below

```
new \DateTime('+8 weekdays');
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

$date = new \DateTime('+8 days');
$date = shiftDate($date);
function shiftDate($date){
    if (in_array((int)$date->format('N'), [6,7])){
        $date->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        $date = shiftDate($date);
    }
    return $date;
}
var_dump($date);
```

working code here https://3v4l.org/vmomV

Comment: Nice! But why doesn't `value="<?php echo $date ?>"` give me the date value in the date input?

Comment: sorry you would need to use `$date->format("Y-m-d")`

Comment: docs on the DateTime object https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Instead of calling your function recursively, you could simply do `->modify('next monday')` if the date is on a weekend.

Comment: @El_Vanja true, I have a more complex version of this that also skips bank holidays and company holidays so in my original version recursion was more appropriate as it could shift to any day of the week in theory.  Glad it worked for you